# How can I prove that $\ln(n)/n\ge\ln(n+1)/(n+1)$ for $n\ge3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that $a_n\ge a_{n+1}$, where $a_n=\frac{\ln\left(n\right)}{n}$
How can I do it?
I tried with induction but it didn't work.

Comment: This is true for $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$$
f(x) = \frac{{\ln (x)}}
{x}
$$
then
$$
f'(x) = \frac{{1 - \ln (x)}}
{{x^2 }}
$$
This means that $f$ is decreasing and this prove what you want.
which is negative for $x \geq e$ .

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate $\frac{\ln x}{x}$, you will see that it is decreasing for $x> e$.